# Beautiful soup missing data (div)

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a webpage with the following format

```
<html class="gr__racinng_applledaily_com_hk" style='overflow: initial;">
<head> ... </head>
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
<!-- Google Tag Mananger (noscript) -->
<noscript> ...</noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Mananger (noscript) -->
<div data-v-6223d6a8 id="app" class="web"> ... </div>
</body>
</html>
```

By using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


page = BeautifulSoup(raw_html.content, 'html.parser')
```

or

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = BeautifulSoup(raw_html.content, 'html5lib')
```

it missed the `<div>` part, is it possible to get it back

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: can you share the source url ?

Comment: https://racing.appledaily.com.hk/race-day/race-position?raceDay=1865&race=15632
desired output is the data on the table which is inside the <div>